# elasticsearch percolator filter fails

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a document query against a percolator that works ok. When I try to filter the percolator queries against which document percolate using queries ids, it doesn't return any result. For example:

```
{
  "doc" : {
   "text" : "This is the text within my document"
  },
  "highlight" : {
   "order" : "score",
   "pre_tags" : ["<example>"],
   "post_tags" : ["</example>"],
   "fields" : {
   "text" : { "number_of_fragments" : 0 }
  }
 },
 "filter":{"ids":{"values":[11,15]}}
,
 "size" : 100
}
```

I know for sure that those ids are correct, but allways obtain `"matches" : [ ]`. When I don't use filter, ES retrieves correct matches.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved it. It seems that [the filter only works on the "metadata" fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html), meaning that you have to add customized fields to the queries indexed in the percolator in order to use them to filter when you need.
Using my previous example, I would have to index in percolator queries like:

```
{
    "query" : {
      "match_phrase" : {
        "text" : "document"
      }
    },
    "id" : 11
  }
```

Adding "manually" a redundant *id* field in order to use it later as filter reference.
At percolation time, you have to use something like:

```
{
  "doc" : {
   "text" : "This is the text within my document"
  },
 "filter":{"match":{"id":11}},
  "highlight" : {
   "order" : "score",
   "pre_tags" : ["<example>"],
   "post_tags" : ["</example>"],
   "fields" : {
   "text" : { "number_of_fragments" : 0 }
  }
 },
 "size" : 100
}
```

In order to use only that percolator query. Complementary information can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/when-and-how-to-percolate-2).